# My code has 2 functions and I want to run only 1 of them

Tags: python

I wrote some code for a guessing game. There are two functions: `guess` - implementing a game where the user guesses the computer's number; and `computer_guess`, for the opposite (the computer guesses the user's number).

Here is the code:

```
import random

def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1, x)
    guess = 0
    while guess != random_number:
        guess = int(input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}:'))
        if guess < random_number:
            print('Sorry, guess again. Too low.')
        elif guess > random_number:
            print('Sorry, guess again. Too high.')
    
    print(f'You guessed it bro, it was {random_number}')

upper_limit = int(input('Give me an upper limit:'))
guess(upper_limit)

def computer_guess(x):
    low = 1
    high = x
    feedback = ''
    while feedback != 'c':
        if low != high:
            guess = random.randint(low, high)
        else:
            guess = low # could also be high b/c low = high
        feedback = input(f'Is {guess} too high (H), too low (L), or correct (C)?').lower()
        if feedback == 'h':
            high = guess - 1
        elif feedback == 'l': 
            low = guess + 1

    print(f'The computer guessed your number, {guess}, correctly')

computer_guess(100)
```

When I run the program in terminal, both functions run. How do I make it so that I can run just one of the functions?

Comment: It runs both functions because you call both functions with `guess(upper_limit)` and `computer_guess(100)`. If you don't want a function to run, don't call it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "When I run the program in terminal it will make me go through both programs 1) and 2). If I only want to run 1 program, what do I do?" It is important to understand both the terminology, and the underlying concepts. You do not have two programs here; you have two **functions** - named `guess` and `computer_guess`. The reason that both functions "run" is that both of them are **called** - the code `guess(upper_limit)` calls `guess`, and the code `computer_guess(100)` calls `computer_guess`.

Comment: As an aside: please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are not interested in your thanks, a sign-off, or anything to do with you as a programmer. We are **only** interested in **the question**, and whatever is needed in order to understand that question. It does not matter what you are using to write the code, unless you think the problem is caused by that tool. Please see how I [edit]ed the question for a model of how to ask clearly and directly.

Answer (score 1):

You call both function in your code:

```
upper_limit = int(input('Give me an upper limit:'))
guess(upper_limit)
```

and

```
computer_guess(100)
```

That causes both of them to run. If you want to run one of them, simply write an `if` and ask which one must run:

```
print("computer or user? 1.computer 2. user")
if int(input()) == 1:
    computer_guess(100)
else:
    upper_limit = int(input('Give me an upper limit:'))
    guess(upper_limit)
```

complete code:

```
import random

def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1, x)
    guess = 0
    while guess != random_number:
        guess = int(input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}:'))
        if guess < random_number:
            print('Sorry, guess again. Too low.')
        elif guess > random_number:
            print('Sorry, guess again. Too high.')
    
    print(f'You guessed it bro, it was {random_number}')

def computer_guess(x):
    low = 1
    high = x
    feedback = ''
    while feedback != 'c':
        if low != high:
            guess = random.randint(low, high)
        else:
            guess = low # could also be high b/c low = high
        feedback = input(f'Is {guess} too high (H), too low (L), or correct (C)?').lower()
        if feedback == 'h':
            high = guess - 1
        elif feedback == 'l': 
            low = guess + 1

    print(f'The computer guessed your number, {guess}, correctly')

print("computer or user? 1.computer 2. user")
if int(input()) == 1:
   computer_guess(100)
else:
    upper_limit = int(input('Give me an upper limit:'))
    guess(upper_limit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running both functions in the code, you could do 2 diferent things to solve it, either make the usar choose, example: take a input from the user, if the input = 1 Run the computer version, eles Run the other. Or you could make ir random by instead of a user integer generate a random Numbers and make the same thing.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make a a loop and it will run until you player choose not to.Code below.

```
import random


def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1, x)
    guess = 0
    while guess != random_number:
        guess = int(input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}:'))
        if guess < random_number:
            print('Sorry, guess again. Too low.')
        elif guess > random_number:
            print('Sorry, guess again. Too high.')

    print(f'You guessed it bro, it was {random_number}')


def computer_guess(x):
    low = 1
    high = x
    feedback = ''
    while feedback != 'c':
        if low != high:
            guess = random.randint(low, high)
        else:
            guess = low  # could also be high b/c low = high
        feedback = input(f'Is {guess} too high (H), too low (L), or correct (C)?').lower()
        if feedback == 'h':
            high = guess - 1
        elif feedback == 'l':
            low = guess + 1

    print(f'The computer guessed your number, {guess}, correctly')


while True:
    choice = input(
        " chose 1 for user input : \n Choose 2 for computer input : \n Choose any other character to exit : \n")

    if choice == '1':
        upper_limit = int(input('Give me an upper limit:'))
        guess(upper_limit)
    elif choice == '2':
        computer_guess(100)
    else:
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you are liking your Python experience so far.

I think the best for you to learn a little good practice for files that needs to be run as script:

- "[`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/)"

In your case, you could simply rearrange the code with imports and function definitions first and then after this `__main__` condition you can simply choose what to execute in this script.py

```py
import random

def guess(x):
    ...

def computer_guess(x):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    upper_limit = int(input('Give me an upper limit:'))
    guess(upper_limit)
    # computer_guess(100)    # just commenting out the 2) function call
```

And then inside that indentation even implement a choosing like the other answers suggested